# Bootstrap container class doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently trying Bootstrap in website development but it seems that the container class, which should center the content isn't working. I can't seem to find the problem as to why it won't work. I've tried a different text editor and downloaded bootstrap again but nothing happens. Text editor I'm using is Sublime text 2.

Thanks for any help! :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sample One</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body class="container">
    <header class="row">
        <hgroup class="span8">
            <h1><a href="img/logo.png" title="Visit website"></a></h1>
            <h2>Sample website design</h2>
        </hgroup>
        <nav class="span4">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" title="About">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="Work">Our Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section role="main">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="" title="Facebook">Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="Twitter">Twitter</a></li>
        </ul>
        <img alt="bg" src=""> 
        <article>
            <h1>Title of the article</h1>
            <p>Sony has revealed lifetime sales of the PS3 has passed another milestone, and announced 300 new games are coming this Christmas.</p>
        </article>
        <section>
            <h1>Portfolio</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="">
                    <h2>Brand name</h2>
                    <p>sdaid dainsd iansd aisndla dansld</p> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="">
                    <h2>Brand name</h2>
                    <p>sdaid dainsd iansd aisndla dansld</p> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="">
                    <h2>Brand name</h2>
                    <p>sdaid dainsd iansd aisndla dansld</p> 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <article>
            <h1>Contact</h1>
            <p>Sony has revealed lifetime sales of the PS3 has passed another milestone, and announced 300 new games are coming this Christmas.</p>
        </article>
    </section>
    <footer class="row">
        <small class="span8">&copy; 2013 All Right Reserved. Designed by Renz</small>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be sure to read the tag descriptions when adding tags to posts. Questions about Twitter Bootstrap should be tagged with `twitter-bootstrap`, not `bootstrap`.

Comment: what version of bootstrap?

Comment: @aaronmallen The bootstrap version is 3.0.1.

Comment: @HouseMistal bootstap released a tweet yesterday indicating that some grid elements where indeed missing: [tweet](https://twitter.com/twbootstrap/status/398197478123520001)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would wrap all your content in a `<div class="container">`, not by applying the class to the `<body>`. Like so:

```
body
  -> .container
     -> .row
        -> .span6
           -> Your content
        -> .span6
           -> More content
     -> .row etc.
```

Comment: Does this apply to the class="row" and class="span*"? I created divs for those as well but it doesn't work.

Comment: I normally go for one `<div class="container">` to wrap everything. Then inside that I'd have a `<div class="row">` for each row of content. Inside those rows I'd have my columns/spans. With Bootstrap rows have to go inside containers to have proper padding.

Answer (score 2):

Don't place `.container` on the `body`, wrap your content in a DIV instead and then apply the container class on that DIV.

Answer (score 0):

No body must give the class of container
but, you must use a new element to the container
example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sample One</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <header class="row">
        <hgroup class="span8">
            <h1><a href="img/logo.png" title="Visit website"></a></h1>
            <h2>Sample website design</h2>
        </hgroup>
        <nav class="span4">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" title="About">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="Work">Our Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section role="main">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="" title="Facebook">Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="" title="Twitter">Twitter</a></li>
        </ul>
        <img alt="bg" src=""> 
        <article>
            <h1>Title of the article</h1>
            <p>Sony has revealed lifetime sales of the PS3 has passed another milestone, and announced 300 new games are coming this Christmas.</p>
        </article>
        <section>
            <h1>Portfolio</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="">
                    <h2>Brand name</h2>
                    <p>sdaid dainsd iansd aisndla dansld</p> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="">
                    <h2>Brand name</h2>
                    <p>sdaid dainsd iansd aisndla dansld</p> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="">
                    <h2>Brand name</h2>
                    <p>sdaid dainsd iansd aisndla dansld</p> 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <article>
            <h1>Contact</h1>
            <p>Sony has revealed lifetime sales of the PS3 has passed another milestone, and announced 300 new games are coming this Christmas.</p>
        </article>
    </section>
    <footer class="row">
        <small class="span8">&copy; 2013 All Right Reserved. Designed by Renz</small>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This has been changed in 3x : .col-md-* rather than span* as:

`<header class="row">
        <hgroup class="col-md-8">`